# How can I change date format in javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker, date-format

In my ruby on rails app I have an object of date like

```
var today_ad = new Date();
```

and I want to get "today_ad" in format "16-07-2014", so I used the code given below

```
var today_informat_ad = today_ad.getDate()+'-'+(today_ad.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today_ad.getFullYear();
```

now the result is "16-7-2014",but my requirement is "16-07-2014 (because I want to compare this date with some other date taken from datepicker which is in format "dd-mm-yyyy".

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var current_date = new Date();
var current_day = padZero(current_date.getDate());
var current_month =  padZero(current_date.getMonth());
var formatted_date = current_day + '-' + current_month + '-' + current_date.getFullYear();


function padZero(numeral) {
    return ('0' + numeral).slice(-2);
}
```